# How to show only product active=0 when using select in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, materialize

I want to show only data active=0. I get all data in JSON like below:

```
{
    "StatusCode": 0,
    "StatusMessage": "OK",
    "StatusDescription": [
        {   "h_id": "1",
            "active": 0,
            "date_created": "2018-08-02T15:28:52.000Z",
            "serial_number": "4324fdfd",
            "client_id": null
        },
        {   "h_id": "2",
            "active": 0,
            "date_created": "2018-08-02T15:28:52.000Z",
            "serial_number": "3435fdf",
            "client_id": null
        },
        {   "h_id": "3",
            "active": 0,
            "date_created": "2018-08-02T15:28:52.000Z",
            "serial_number": "fgdge43",
            "client_id": null 
        },
        {   "h_id": "4",
            "active": 1,
            "date_created": "2018-08-02T15:28:52.000Z",
            "serial_number": "edf43",
            "client_id": 1
        },
        {
            "h_id": "5",
            "active": 1,
            "date_created": "2018-08-02T15:28:52.000Z",
            "serial_number": "3456677777",
            "client_id": 2
        },
        ....
        {
           "h_id": "10",
            "active": 1,
            "date_created": "2018-08-02T15:28:52.000Z",
            "serial_number": "JDLk32",
            "client_id": 200
        }
      ]
     }
```

In html I write this code to show all data in drop down:

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <select formControlName="h_id" id="h_id" materialize="material_select" [materializeSelectOptions]="hbp" >
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Hb</option>
    <option *ngFor="let hb of hbp" [value]="hb.h_id">{{hb.serial_number}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

All value show correct in drop down select, but I want to show in drop down only hb that have **`active:0`**

Please, can you ask me any idea how to show only data `active = 0` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a getter in your component.

```js
get zeroHbp() {
  return this.hbp && this.hbp.filter(hb => hb.active === 0) || [];
}
```

```html
<option *ngFor="let hb of zeroHbp" [value]="hb.h_id">{{hb.serial_number}}</option>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Try *ngIf for condition in ng-container

```
**<select>
   <ng-container *ngFor="let hb of hbp">
     <option *ngIf="hb.active == 0"  [ngValue]="hb.h_id" ></option>
   </ng-container>
</select>**
```

Comment: Btw, unfortunately **bolding**  (i.e. using `**`) isn't supported for code snippets. (Tried to [edit] the question but it was rejected for too few characters)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your html code to something like this:

```
<select id="h_id">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Select Hb</option>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let hb of hbp.StatusDescription">
    <option *ngIf="hb.active === 0">{{hb.serial_number}}</option>
  </ng-container>
</select>
```